# Maven test in a different phase

Tags: unit-testing, maven

At present I have some very heavy tests that I only want to run before I install a Maven package.  I'm having trouble communicating this to my pom, which so far includes:

```
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.13</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>dummied-test</id>
       <phase>test</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>test</goal>
       </goals>
       <configuration>
         <skip>true</skip>
       </configuration>
     </execution>
     <execution>
       <id>test-in-verify-phase</id>
       <phase>verify</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>test</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>
```

You can guess that I 1) first tried binding it to the `verify` phase, 2) tried explicitly adding it to the `test` phase with no goals, 3) added it to the `test` phase with `skip` set to true...

How do I tell Maven to not run tests in the test phase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add the `configuration` tag outside of the `executions` tag.  Why?  I don't fully understand this but I imagine I just merely added another execution that skipped tests.  Per this resource:  http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=62120